# Python Run System Command and Save Output

Tags: python-2.7

1) Write a python program that runs a system command (i.e. "dir" )
2) Save the output of the system command into a variable
3) Print the variable

This is done in Python, I can't figure this out, I found one that only returned me "0" using subprocess.

I'm using Wndows 7 Python 2.5 and 2.7

Basically, I want the output of something like cmd -> dir C:\

Then that output gets saved to a file using Python.

Help would be nice,

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`subprocess.check_output`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

From the docs:

> `subprocess.check_output(args, stdin=None, stderr=None, shell=False,
>   universal_newlines=False)`
>
> Run command with arguments and return its
>   output as a byte string.

Example:

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["echo", "Hello World!"])
'Hello World!\n'
```

Comment: I get a syntax error after (args,) with (*,)

Comment: @Sublimity Um, I'm not sure what the `*` is supposed to mean there, but you are not supposed to put it in the function call. Try something  like `check_output(['dir', 'C:\\'])`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a class I found [elsewhere](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/257449/a-command-class-to-run-shell-commands) that appears to accomplish what you are looking for

```
class Command(object):
    """Run a command and capture it's output string, error string and exit status"""
    def __init__(self, command):
        self.command = command
    def run(self, shell=True):
        import subprocess as sp
        process = sp.Popen(self.command, shell = shell, stdout = sp.PIPE, stderr = sp.PIPE)
        self.pid = process.pid
        self.output, self.error = process.communicate()
        self.failed = process.returncode
        return self
    @property
    def returncode(self):
        return self.failed
```

To run it, just do the following:

```
commandVar = Command("dir").run()
```

then to view the result:

```
commandVar.output
```

Comment: I get in return an error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/My_Name/Desktop/cmd.py", line 15, in <module>
    commandVar = command("dir").run()
NameError: name 'command' is not defined

Comment: @Sublimity It probably should be `Command`, the class name.